# Search Results Web results Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug

Tags: react-native

Code is running but I got this error. The app is not installed to the emulator. Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
PS D:\3rd Year\Mobile Application Development\Projec\ChatBot\ChatBot> react-native run-android
    info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
    Jetifier found 1152 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
    info JS server already running.
    info Installing the app...
    > Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
    
    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
    Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
    See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    105 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 102 up-to-date
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
       > Unable to delete directory 'D:\3rd Year\Mobile Application Development\Projec\ChatBot\ChatBot\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\r\com\facebook\drawee\backends' after 10 attempts
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 20s
    
    error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
    Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this error :app:processDebugResources, it can be caused by many reasons, but my error was solved by cleaning the gradle you can clean it using this command `cd android && gradlew clean` run this in the root folder of your project.

Also, make sure that your android device is available in the ADB.
run command `adb devices` to get a list of devices running currently. if the list is empty then you need to fix your android emulator or device it must be connected with adb.